# Objective-c - Replace #import with #define

Tags: objective-c, xcode, preprocessor-directive

Is there a way to replace a class name #import through a #define macro? I want it to be made in all my project and not just in one file. So I don't want to make a #ifdef / #ifndef in each class that include the #import that I want to replace.

Something like... I have

```
#import "ClassSomething.h"
```

in 5 classes. I want to replace it with an

```
#import "ClassSomethingCustom.h"
```

but only

```
#ifdef SomethingIsDefined
```

Comment: This is a really bad design.

Comment: @Andy: I know that. Maybe sometimes you are forced to do it or do you think I like bad designing? :-)

Comment: I understand. Maybe you could get away with categories or maybe you could switch ISA on modern runtime. Sometimes the best approach is to copy code and change it if you plan drastic changes. It gets less risky. Or maybe, you could resolve this on Filesystem level and create symlinks or something. There are many ways.

Comment: I think you need re-check your import architecture, very bad idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Objective-C's compiler (gcc or clang) do a good job of not cluttering the compiled source with duplicated header information.  There's nothing wrong with including both headers - unless the headers re-define the same class (which is what I suspect is the case here).

Replace `#import "ClassSomething.h"` in all your files with `#import CLASS_SOMETHING_HEADER`

Then, in your `.pch` file, have the following:

```
#ifdef SomethingIsDefined
    #define CLASS_SOMETHING_HEADER "ClassSomethingCustom.h" 
#else
    #define CLASS_SOMETHING_HEADER "ClassSomething.h"
#endif
```

This isn't really ideal, though, as pre-processor macros that deal with imports can lead to many unforeseen errors. It's not a common pattern and future developers may not properly understand what you've done.

Another option you might want to consider is a pattern that is commonly used in libraries that support both iOS and OS X.

```
#ifdef SOME_IOS_IDENTIFIER_I_FORGOT_TO_LOOK_UP
    typedef UIColor MyColor
#else
    typedef NSColor MyColor
#endif
```

In this case you'd name your two classes differently and use an alias to reference them in your source. Place the relevant imports in a "parent" header file like "MyProjectImports.h" or something.  (where you'd import `AppKit` or `UIKit`)

Alternatively, you might want to consider using a `Category` on `ClassSomething` (i.e. "ClassSomething+Custom.h") to include the custom functionality you need.  This will likely require some re-working of the logic underlying the two different classes, but in the files that need just the custom behavior, can conditionally `#import` the Category header and the other files can be left alone.

Without more knowledge on exactly *how* these two classes differ or will be used, I can't help you much further.

HtH

Answer (score 1):

Put this into a header file:

```
#ifdef SomethingIsDefined
#import "ClassSomethingCustom.h" 
#else
#import "ClassSomething.h"
#endif
```

and include this header file in you 5 classes.

Comment: I thought about that but in that way I have to create an header for each class that I want to customize. It will work, but I was looking for something more programmatic. Like a single header where all these substitution are made. And I also didn't want do modify all the projects where there is already an #import "ClassSomething.h".

Answer (score 0):

You can change the content `ClassSomething.h` and put the `#ifdef SomethingIsDefined` only in there.

Comment: That won't help. I need to import ClassSomethingCustom instead of ClassSomething, so I have to make that change in the class which are now including ClassSomething. Not in that class itself.

Comment: If you don't want to edit the 5 sources that include `ClassSomething.h`, the only way is the edit the `ClassSomething.h` itself so that if `SomethingIsDefined` is defined, it'll expose `ClassSomething` otherwise, it'll expose `ClassSomethingCustom`. This means you'll have to put both `ClassSomething` and `ClassSomethingCustom` declarations inside `ClassSomething.h` and switch them through the `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is to paste the code @dasdom wrote into your .pch file (pre-compiled header) file instead of every header. With that, you only need to paste it once and all the files will add this header automatically

```
#ifdef SomethingIsDefined
#import "ClassSomethingCustom.h" 
#else
#import "ClassSomething.h"
#endif
```

I hope this helps you. Otherwise, please can you explain it deeply?

Comment: As I said to @dasdom that won't fit my question because in that way all my classes will include either ClassSomethingCustom or ClassSomething. That would be a deal if I haven't a really lot of classes to customize. I can't import in all classes like 25-30 classes that I won't use.

P.S.
The big problem is that I'm making a "core" project which will be included in other projects but it has to adapt to these projects "listening" if they are implementing the customization of the classes or che "core" version of them.

Comment: @AlbertoSchiariti I'll be honest with you I don't think there is any other way of doing what you are after except for the ways that are getting suggested and you are saying they will not do.

Comment: @Popeye I had the suspect. That's why I wanted to hear some colleagues here :-)